# How to publish an Angular and dotnet Web api project in VS code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, publish

Following these tutorials: [tutorial1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1206306/Integrating-ASP-Net-Core-and-Angular-projec) - [tutorial2](https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa) I now have a working hello world project that works great. Problem is that I dont know how to publish the whole project so I can upload the files to my webhost provider.

This is my project in VS code (the app.component.html holds the content):

[image]

`dotnet publish --outdir C:\temp` publishes to the folder, but the html file is missing (not in the src folder either):
[image]

`ng build` builds the angular project to wwwroot. In this folder there is an index.html file, but it is empty:

[image]

When I normally run the project from VS code with F5, it seems like the dotnet core Kestrel web server does not host the files anywhere, but instead use the files directly in the project.
So how do you publish a project like this, so I can upload the files to my webhost? Just like when I push F5 in VS code.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176085/angular-2-app-publish-not-working-on-net-hosting/48182751#48182751

Comment: Thanks, but it really did not help. The two projects are not bundled together.

Comment: First you need to take a build of your project Ex: npm build. After taking build the file will be stored in particular folder like "dist" as your configuration  and you can host that build file in Server

Comment: Yea I can build the angular project with 'ng build'. This builds some js bundle and map files, and an empty index.html file. The app.component.html file (from the tutorial i mentioned) is gone, and this is where the frontend logic is. And what about the web api backend files? They should be combined with the angular build...

Comment: It is new Angular CLI version I guess. Dotnet publish will handle both your c# and angular code. When you publish, the html file must be in wwwroot folder not in dist folder.

Comment: `dotnet publish -c Release` btw

Comment: When i publish like you say, the result is like the screenshots. In the wwwroot folder, the only html file that exists is the empty one..

Comment: Are you trying to publish to IIS?

Comment: Yes I am trying to publish to IIS.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Sorry, JCircio, I did not get an answer to this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use de Angular template in Visual Studio 2017.
You must change your index.cshtml like

```
<!-- comment this line
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
    -->
<!--just only-->
<app>Loading...</app>
```

Change your package.json to use angular 5

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "5.1.2",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.9.2",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
    "@types/quill": "1.3.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.3",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.4.1",
    "chai": "4.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.6",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.9",
    "preboot": "6.0.0-beta.1",
    "quill": "1.3.4",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "style-loader": "0.19.1",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.21.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-css-only": "4.0.0-beta.2", //<--if you want to use bootstrap.css but not all bootstrap
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2"
  }
```

I think that it's all

Comment: I am using VS code, and not VS 2017. I cant see how changing my dependencies will work? When I build and run the project from VS code everything works perfectly, and it is these build files I would like to get.

Comment: sorry, :(. You must use dotnet build to build an application. I don't have experiencie, check the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x